# VSTO "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: vsto, build-error, vs-error

I'm getting an error compiling my VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) project in VS.

It says **"Value does not fall within the expected range."** and **"There was an error during installation"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha. The **path** of my project was **too deep.**

**Ans:** Move it a few folders above *(in the Windows Explorer folder tree)* and try **re-building**/ re-running again.

Answer (score 1):

> Gotcha. The **path** of the project was **too
>   deep.**
>
> Move the project a few folders above (in
>   the Windows Explorer folder tree) and
>   try **re-building**/ re-running again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before when I tied to install the `vsto` with the `vsto` file.

Publish your application and install the setup and the problem disappeared.

To publishing => *Project Properties / Publish / Select Folder Path / Publish Now*